# alire cannot run hello programm error code 35

Tags: ada

Hello I am trying to run Hello program on Alire on Windows but can't I get this error, can someone help?

```
Note: Selected tool version gprbuild=22.0.1
Note: Deploying gprbuild=22.0.1...
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - La fonction de révocation n'a pas pu vérifier la révocation du certificat.

Fichier introuvable - C:\alire\.config\alire\cache\dependencies\alr-gpyu.tmp\*
Fichier introuvable - C:\alire\.config\alire\cache\dependencies\alr-gpyu.tmp\*
ERROR: Command ["curl", "https://github.com/alire-project/GNAT-FSF-builds/releases/download/gprbuild-22.0.0-1/gprbuild-x86_64-windows64-22.0.0-1.tar.gz", "--location", "--progress-bar", "--output", "C:\alire\.config\alire\cache\dependencies\alr-gpyu.tmp\gprbuild-x86_64-windows64-22.0.0-1.tar.gz"] exited with code 35
```

Comment: the problem seems to be with `curl` and expired/revoked security certificates, not alire itself

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by downloading gnat and gprbuild from github and changing env parameters: with the commands